# Inserting multiple rows in a while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, implode

I'm trying to insert multiple rows in a while loop with a form using implode but cannot seem to make it work. I want to insert multiple values named "weight". Like values 30,20,15,10,5 and the remaining emp_id and task_id.

page1.php

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    task_tbl.task_id,
                    task_tbl.task_name,
                    task_tbl.task_sem,
                    task_tbl.task_yr,
                    task_tbl.post_id,
                    post_tbl.post_id,
                    post_tbl.post_name AS ppost_name
                    FROM 
                    task_tbl 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    post_tbl
                    ON
                    task_tbl.post_id = post_tbl.post_id 
                    WHERE 
                    task_sem = '$sem' 
                    AND 
                    task_yr = '$yr' 
                    ORDER BY 
                    task_id ASC");

echo '<form action = "upds_peval.php" name = "add" method = "post">';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<b>Employee ID No.:</b>"; 
        echo '<input size = "2" type = "text" name = "emp_id'.$id.'" value = "';
        echo $_POST['emp_id'];
        echo '"/>';
        echo "<br/>";   
        echo "<b>Work/Activity ID No.:</b> ";
        echo '<input size = "2" type = "text" name = "task_id'.$row['task_id'].'" value = "';
        echo $row['task_id'];
        echo '"/>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<b>Work/Activity:</b> ";
        echo $row['task_name'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<b>Weight:</b> ";
        echo '<input size = "1" type="text" name="weight" value = ""/>';
        echo "%";
        echo "<br/>";

        }

        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD"/>';
        echo "</form>";
```

the output would be like:

Employee ID No.: 1001
Work/Activity ID No.: 2002
Work/Activity: Supervises Maintenance and Troubleshooting of Computers
Weight: [__]%

Employee ID No.: 1001
Work/Activity ID No.: 2003
Work/Activity: Supervises Software Installation and Maintenance
Weight: [__]%

Employee ID No.: 1001
Work/Activity ID No.: 2004
Work/Activity: Maintains, Monitors, and Troubleshoots Virtual Terminals
Weight: [__]%

|SUBMIT|

page2.php

```
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("emp_db0");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_POST['weight'];


    $vals=implode(",",$_POST);  

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO peval_tbl(weight,task_id,emp_id) VALUES('$vals')");
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "You have successfully added work/activities!";
    echo "<br/>";   
    }
```

Comment: The output should be, but what are you getting? Nothing? Wrong output?

Comment: are you assigning the value of `$_POST['weight']` to any variable? what value is contained by your `$_POST` in your statement `$vals = implode(",",$_POST)` ?

Comment: Why are you using implode?  Why not just '".$_POST['weight']."','".$_POST['task_id']."','".$_POST['emp_id']."'

Comment: Also what is $_POST['weight']; doing?

Comment: well no output for page2.php. im trying to debug. probably its wrong. i dont know yet. still guessing wat could work

Comment: supposedly $_POST['weight'] will fetch the value from the form inside the loop in page1.php and insert the value in the table. as for implode, im thinking it will get all the queries with its rows and its values in the loop and insert everything in the table.

Comment: i did try somehow but the only value im getting at is the last query at the bottom. For example, U see my sample output for page1.php? When I must put 30,40,15, at those <input> and when I submit, all the values will be insert into the table simultaneously at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay based on my impression of your question, you want a form that is extensible right, where you can access all of its instance in one name?

1st Instance of form sample:

```
<input size = "2" type = "text" name = "emp_id[]" value = "1">
<input size = "2" type = "text" name = "task_id[]" value = "5001">
<input size = "2" type = "text" name = "weight[]" value = "50">
```

2nd Instance sample:

```
<input size = "2" type = "text" name = "emp_id[]" value = "2">
<input size = "2" type = "text" name = "task_id[]" value = "5003">
<input size = "2" type = "text" name = "weight[]" value = "30">
```

this will convert your posts into arrays

to access:

```
$var_emp_id = $_POST["emp_id"];
$var_task_id = $_POST["task_id"];
$var_weight_id = $_POST["weight"];
```

use a loop to access those variables.
to access the first instance of emp_id u use:

```
$var_emp_id[0]; //will output 1
$var_emp_id[1]; //will output 2

$var_task_id[0]; //will output 5001
$var_task_id[1]; //will output 5003
```

to insert it on your database:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($var_emp_id); $i++){
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO peval_tbl(weight,task_id,emp_id) VALUES('$weight[$i]','$var_task_id[$i]','$var_emp_id[$i]')");
}
```

Comment: np :), but i suggest you use PDO or mysqli for your Queries, mysql_query already has been depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are addressing the $_POST array incorrectly, so rather than recode your script try this.

Add this line to your code in page2.php before the mysql_connect

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST,true) . '</pre>';
```

This will dump a nice print of the post array so you can see how data arrives in $_POST.

Comment: `Array
(
    [emp_id] => 1001
    [task_id5001] => 5001
    [weight] => 90
    [task_id5002] => 5002
    [task_id5003] => 5003
    [task_id5004] => 5004
    [task_id5005] => 5005
    [task_id5006] => 5006
    [task_id5009] => 5009
    [submit] => ADD
)`

Comment: the name "wieght" is wrong. tsk. How do I call them one by one and insert them altogether?

Comment: use **foreach**, sir @raziel2101 you may want to learn **PDO** or MVC Frameworks such as **CodeIgniter, CakePHP** mysql_* functions are no longer used because of some issues like securtiy.

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "select * from login where nombre !='carlos'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$index = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $valor = $row["nombre"];
    $valor2 = $row["apellido"];
    $insertsql= "insert into lista (`dato1`,`dato2`)values ('$valor', now())";
    // mysql_query($insertsql);
    $conn->query($insertsql);
    $index++;
}
```

http://www.baulphp.com/insertar-multiples-registros-ciclo-while-php/